# Lua print ASCII table

Tags: unicode, lua, ascii, utf-16, non-ascii-characters

1. I want to print as ASCII table of the first 0-512 chars in the table of 16 rows, thus making it 16 rows, 32 columns. But I wonder how I can make sure the real characters and not just Unicode encodings will come out in the ranges after 128-512? Also, is there any special hex or bin trick to set the counter in a non-decimal way?
2. Another question was how to make a ASCII table with the CTRL and ESC codes that come in the 128 - 192 range. I do not even know how to approach the question of finding the CTRL and ESC codes in lua or some standard library.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ASCII is usually only for 256 chars. What is ASCII 300?

Comment: Anyway, the relevant function is `string.char`.

Comment: Where do you want to print your table to?  To Windows console?

Comment: Standard ASCII is 7-bit and, therefore, goes from 0 to 127.  Extended ASCII (8-bit ASCII) which isn't really a standard goes up to 255.  Above that you don't call it ASCII.  Unicode and ASCII are not the same.

Comment: Thank you all. To OSX console.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense, as @tonypdmtr pointed out. ASCII only has 128 characters. Please clarify your question or you won't be getting much help (can't help you if we don't know what you even want)

Comment: @DmitryStarostin - `for c = 32, 555 do print(c, utf8.char(c)) end`  This should work with Lua 5.3 on OSX console.  BTW, I've read your question twice, but didn't understand what exactly your problem is.  Say it in Russian please.

Comment: There are many standard character sets that fall into the loosely defined Extended ASCII family. Since there is ultimately only one important character set and encoding-the one you choose to use-the term Extended ASCII is almost always too vague to have any value. ASCII has 128 codepoints. So, what are you asking about?

Comment: 1. standalone `for c = 32, 555 do print(c, utf8.char(c))` does nothing in Lua 5.3.5 console, OSX. 2. I have better knowledge of programmer's English since all mans are in it, would not be worth the time to formulate in Russian. 3. The question was simple: for the ranges of dec 128-159 I will get what? 0x8b for dec. 139? I suspect it won't be PLD or ESCAPE K.